# Deploy GWT app in Openshift

Tags: java, maven, gwt, jboss, openshift

I am trying to deploy a GWT App to Openshift/JBossAS.

My problem is that even my app works locally with `$mvn gwt run:codeserver`

When I do push to the Openshift cloud I can see this error in the logs:

```
remote: [INFO]    Found 2748 cached/archived units.  Used 2748 / 4044 units from cache.
remote: [INFO]    Compiling...
remote: [ERROR] Dec 18, 2014 5:09:09 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences checkLockFile0ErrorCode
remote: [ERROR] WARNING: Could not lock User prefs.  Unix error code 2.
remote: [ERROR] Dec 18, 2014 5:09:09 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences syncWorld
remote: [ERROR] WARNING: Couldn't flush user prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock.
remote: [INFO]       0% complete (ETR: 79 seconds)
remote: [INFO]       10% complete (ETR: 58 seconds)
remote: [INFO]       20% complete (ETR: 40 seconds)
remote: [INFO]       30% complete (ETR: 28 seconds)
remote: [INFO]       40% complete (ETR: 24 seconds)
remote: [INFO]       50% complete (ETR: 20 seconds)
remote: [INFO]       60% complete (ETR: 14 seconds)
remote: [INFO]       70% complete (ETR: 10 seconds)
remote: [INFO]       80% complete (ETR: 7 seconds)
remote: [INFO]       90% complete (ETR: 3 seconds)
remote: [INFO]       100% complete (ETR: 0 seconds)
remote: [INFO]       Compilation completed in 43.70 seconds
remote: [INFO]    Added 4044 units to cache since last cleanup.
remote: [INFO]    Validating units:
remote: [INFO]    Removing invalidated units
remote: [ERROR] Dec 18, 2014 5:09:39 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences checkLockFile0ErrorCode
remote: [ERROR] WARNING: Could not lock User prefs.  Unix error code 2.
remote: [ERROR] Dec 18, 2014 5:09:39 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences syncWorld
remote: [ERROR] WARNING: Couldn't flush user prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock.
remote: [INFO] Wrote 4044 units to persistent cache.
Connection to app-mycompany.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: error in sideband demultiplexer
```

And my app is not getting deployed. Is it not possible to deploy GWT app in Openshift?

Comment: If I include in the git commit files the '/deployments/ROOT.war' would that fix it?

Comment: Yes, I would check in the compiled .war file - the openshift system doesnt seem to have the resources/capabilities to run the GWT compiler.

Comment: does it work? Can you make an answer for it to make it clear.